# Salesforce LWC Editor chrome extension error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, salesforce, lwc

chrome showing error "This extension violates the Chrome Web Store policy" for Salesforce LWC Editor.
should I delte it? and what is the alternative?

Answer (score -1):

Here you go - https://allthings.how/solved-this-extension-violates-the-chrome-web-store-policy/

I was facing a similar issue, I usually reinstall the extension to make it work. Try the link above.